How to share code in different Jupyter notebooks in subfolders?
I need to create a Github repository where I can organize Jupyter notebooks by topic as tutorials. Some notebooks will require to load large(r) data files, which I don't want to be part of the repository themselves.
My idea is to provide all data files in a different online resource, and download the required files in the notebooks using some custom auxiliary method in some utils.py script.
Since I want to use different subfolders for organizing the notebooks, utils.py would need to reside in a parent folder. However, loading .py files from a parent folder within a notebook seems to require manually tweaking the class path in the notebook.
I guess an alternative would be to put utils.py (and other shared code) into its own package that needs to be installed before using the notebook. Kind feels like overkill?
Is there some other and better alternative to handle this.

nbgitpuller can be used to keep notebook content separate from environments. In a different, but related topic, MyBinder documentation spells out a few possibilities suggested your environment separate from your content. See here. For example, I like to use postBuild or start configuration files to move the content over either after the image is built or the session starts, respectively. Here is an ...

 example with start. I know this way using repo2docker and binderhubs isn't quite what you asked but I think the solutions used by those well-versed in the Jupyter ecosystem might help you in thinking about things.

Use a single utils.py file and structuring notebooks into topic-based folders.
Christian_tutorials/
│
├── utils.py                    
│
├── data/                          
└── notebooks/
    ├── topic1/
    │   ├── notebook1.ipynb
    │   └── notebook2.ipynb
    └── topic2/
        └── notebook3.ipynb

Assumptions
Utils.py - Assuming shared functions here.
data/- Assumng local folder forthe storage and download.

Accessing the utils
import sys
sys.path.append('../..')  
from utils import get_data

# Now you can use it to get data:
data_file = get_data(
    filename="example.csv",
    url="https://storage_url/example.csv"
)


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data_file)

utils.py
import os
import requests
from pathlib import Path

def get_data(filename, url):
    data_dir = Path("data")
    data_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    file_path = data_dir / filename
    if not file_path.exists():
        print(f"Downloading {filename}...")
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print("Download complete!")
    return file_path

The get_data function streamlines data handling by creating a data folder if it doesn’t exist, checking for the requested file, and downloading it only if necessary

Yes, this is more or less the file structure I had in mind; I also have auxiliary methods such as get_data(), unzip_file(), etc. already. I was mainly wondering if I can avoid appending the path in each notebook, is it would introduce one more point of failure.

if you want to keep things simple and not mess with making a package, you can just tweak the python path right at the start of your notebook. it's pretty straightforward. here's how you can do it:
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../') 

import utils

just drop this snippet into each notebook where you need it, and you are good to go.

Thanks! It indeed seems to be the most practical solutions. I just had kind of the goal to keep the notebooks as clean as possible.

You're welcome! :)
